# Filepath for database in application

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I have a SQL database on the server and I want to import it to Visual Studio. I executed the script and a copy of the database was created in VS. Now what I want is to include the Database in to the project folder and I want to know the path of the Database relative to the application.

Also what should I do so that the installation file includes the database as well.

I am working in .NET WPF

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database**. SQL is just the Structured Query Language, a language used by many database systems, but it's not a product in itself. We really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: @marc_s it can be assumed he's referring to MSSQL Server.

Comment: @Dai: maybe - but maybe, he's using MySQL - or Oracle - or IBM DB2 - or Postgres - or something else. We shouldn't have to be guessing - the OP should tell us

Comment: @Dai: I agree with Marc. The question is vague: "a SQL database" could mean many things. You can't get "a copy of the database created in VS", because Visual Studio is an IDE. ".NET WPF" is available in several different languages. And you don't "import" a database "to Visual Studio". The question should be edited by the poster to make it more clear, and the appropriate tags should be added.

Comment: @KenWhite Visual Studio has built-in tools for creating MSSQL databases.

Comment: @Dai: I'm well aware, but thanks. :-) It doesn't change anything I said in my comment, though. There are tags available that could make the question more specific, and it could provide additional details. We shouldn't have to assume (or guess) at anything; the poster is asking us to help them, and should provide the information. This is not the first question this poster has asked (or answered) here.